# Could I get a list of modules that I installed using easy_install?

Tags: python, easy-install

Recently, I installed [trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_package_manager) on my local machine for testing purposes.

To get it running, I needed to install several support modules using `easy_install`.

Now, I'm going to take my local installation and move it to a real server that has no Python installed yet.

While moving the trac installation itself seems trivial (http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBackup, https://serverfault.com/questions/6147/how-do-i-backup-my-trac-instalations), actually getting it running needs the modules that I installed with `easy_install`.

Is there a convenient way (such as for example [PPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_package_manager) for Perl) that I could use in order to get the same modules installed on the server that I have on my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use pip, only use easy_install, try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk

Comment: `yolk -l` hows me exactly what I wanted. Thanks! Preferring this answer over Ahsan's since `help('modules')` also lists built-in modules...

Answer (score 0):

Install `Pip`, and then

```
pip freeze
```

You can also use help function in python to get the list of modules installed. Get into python prompt and type the following command.

```
help('modules')
```